# Windows 10 task manager CPU clock speed exceeds displayed maximum clock speed?

Tags: performance, cpu, overclocking, clockspeed

So in the windows task manager, in the performance tab, there's data concerning current clock speed and beside it is stated "maximum speed".

Maximum speed is stated 2.00 GHz, which is correct as per my CPU specs.

On the contrary, though, I see the current clock speed displayed sometimes exceeds 2 GHz (usually around 2 - 3 Ghz) during spikes.

Is this just a glitch in the task manager or is my CPU being overclocked?

Processor is Intel Core i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00 GHz (quad-core)

Comment: What's the CPU type & number?

Answer (score 4):

As a Core i7 processor, your CPU is equipped with Intel Turbo Boost. Your maximum clockspeed is **2.9 Ghz** and NOT 2.0 Ghz:

http://ark.intel.com/products/52219/Intel-Core-i7-2630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz

> Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM Processor  (6M Cache, **up to 2.90 GHz**)
>
> Processor Base Frequency  2 GHz
>
> Max Turbo Frequency   2.9 GHz

What you are seeing is the effect of Turbo Boost in action:

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 accelerates processor and graphics
> performance for peak loads, automatically allowing processor cores to
> run faster than the rated operating frequency if they’re operating
> below power, current, and temperature specification limits. Whether
> the processor enters into Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 and the
> amount of time the processor spends in that state depends on the
> workload and operating environment.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html