# Windows 10 Task Manager: CPU Speed Rises Above Maximum Speed

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance

I wonder if it Windows 10 changing behaviour in recent major update. I am using Windows 10.0.10586. I am well aware of TurboBoost that mentioned in [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/982829/windows-10-task-manager-cpu-clock-speed-exceeds-displayed-maximum-clock-speed). My CPU could hit 2.70GHz in single core mode as specified in the [documentation](http://ark.intel.com/products/81016/Intel-Core-i5-4210U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz).

However, it's rather a no brainer as earlier in Windows 8.1 I never hit more than 2.40GHz. Is it Microsoft changing behaviour to milk more power or something else? - if it something else, I suspect Intel Dynamic Platform & Thermal Framework driver is actually involved.

Anyway, I need some insight.

[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

Comment: [Similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/721248/how-does-intel-turbo-boost-work)

Comment: well, it indeed cover almost the same topic - turbo bost. but, here i am wondering *xx Ghz in your case is the design limit at which processor can run continuously for long time given the standard cooling is working properly.* - why did it rises >2.4GHz although i only use 9% of it? should i cap it a little in power configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task Manager is correct in its measurement of your current speed, but it only reports the CPU's *base frequency* as its max speed. If you look at [your CPU's specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/81016/Intel-Core-i5-4210U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz), you'll see that its max *Turbo frequency* is indeed 2.7 GHz.

Intel Turbo Boost is controlled with ACPI and can also be referred to as "dynamic overclocking." Since the OS does have some control over the processor via ACPI, it is possible that Windows 10 operates your CPU differently than Windows 8.

Further reading: [Intel's page about Turbo Boost 2.0](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html), [Wikipedia's article on ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)

Comment: Turbo Boost is activated when the operating system requests the highest performance state of the processor. Processor performance states are defined by the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) specification, an open standard supported by all major operating systems; no additional software or drivers are required to support the technology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost

Comment: still i am wondering why Microsoft employs such aggressive measures. i barely runs anything heavy just a browser with several tabs and several applications (as the screenshot suggest i had only 72 processes and 9% utilization, it peak almost 20% but never rise above). and such approach certainly had risks regarding how TurboBoost works and the cost on battery life time.

Comment: @Tezla Windows determined (based on temperature and power draw) that it would save you some time by upping the clock speed. This can only happen if all cores' utilization is 100%. It is, in general, better for *overall* power usage to get stuff through the CPU as fast as possible. See [Raymond Chen's post on the subject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101203-00/?p=12123).

Comment: ah i see, perhaps i should reconfigure my power settings to fit my needs and prevent Windows throttle up too much.